# Modular group representation

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-group

Does anyone know how to describe Möbius transformations with integer coefficients defined on the upper half plane in terms of $z+1$ and $1/z$? Some people call it the modular group.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group

Comment: Also, the title is a bit misleading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_representation :)

Comment: @tomasz , "a bit"? It's a completely different branch!